# Initializing a queryset for a dropdown field in a ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a problem with filtering a queryset through a list of object ID's. Upon form submission, the error `[{'item': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}]` shows up. When passing `req` (a list of integers) into a filtered queryset, Django does not accept `req` as a set of valid choices/objects and does not save the form. However, when passing a preset list that contains the same values as `req`, Django accepts and saves the form. I tried printing if `req` is equal to the same preset list and it returned True.

*views.py*

```
class TransferAddView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
...
    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        ctx = self.get_context_data()
        inlines = ctx['inlines']
        form.instance.requisition = ctx['req']
        if inlines.is_valid() and form.is_valid():
            tran = form.save()
            inlines.instance = tran
            inlines.save()
        return super(TransferAddView, self).form_valid(form)
    
    

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx=super(TransferAddView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['req'] = MaterialRequisition.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['req'])
        req = list(MaterialRequisitionItems.objects.filter(requisition=ctx['req']).values_list('item', flat=True))
        ctx['item'] = Item.objects.filter(item__in=req)
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            ctx['form']=TransferModelForm(self.request.POST)
            ctx['inlines']=TransferInlineFormSet(self.request.POST)
            ctx['form'].fields['transferStatus'].initial = 0
        else:
            ctx['form']=TransferModelForm()
            ctx['form'].fields['transferStatus'].initial = 0
            ctx['inlines']=TransferInlineFormSet(form_kwargs={'req':ctx['req'].pk})
        return ctx
```

*forms.py*

```
class TransferItemsModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        req = kwargs.pop('req', None)
        super(TransferItemsModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
        req = list(MaterialRequisitionItems.objects.filter(requisition=req).values_list('item', flat=True))
        self.fields['item'].queryset = Item.objects.filter(item__in=req)
```

Answer (score 1):

I may have figured out how to do this properly. I changed `req` to `reqs` then I passed `reqs` into the formset in the POST method and tweaked it a little bit. Now the `get_context_data` in the views look like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx=super(TransferAddView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['req'] = MaterialRequisition.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['req'])
        req = list(MaterialRequisitionItems.objects.filter(requisition=ctx['req']).values_list('item', flat=True))
        ctx['item'] = Item.objects.filter(item__in=req)
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            ctx['form']=TransferModelForm(self.request.POST)
            ctx['inlines']=TransferInlineFormSet(self.request.POST, form_kwargs={'reqs': list(MaterialRequisitionItems.objects.filter(requisition=ctx['req'].pk).values_list('item', flat=True))})
            ctx['form'].fields['transferStatus'].initial = 0
        else:
            ctx['form']=TransferModelForm()
            ctx['form'].fields['transferStatus'].initial = 0
            ctx['inlines']=TransferInlineFormSet(form_kwargs={'reqs': list(MaterialRequisitionItems.objects.filter(requisition=ctx['req'].pk).values_list('item', flat=True))})
        return ctx
```